# Content Alignment in Libre office is different from MS Office

Tags: libreoffice

I have created a word document using MS Office (.doc), It contains words and lines.

When I opened that document with Libre Office in Ubuntu 12.04 some words and lines alignment is totally different from MS word.

Is there any Solution to solve this problem?

Comment: If you are still using the default version of LibreOffice (3.5) for 12.04 it is worth getting the latest version (4.2) from the LibreOffice PPA - Word compatibility has improved a bit, although no guarantees that your particular issue is solved. (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa` in a terminal, then run update manager to pick up the new version)

Comment: Also, fonts can play a role in word spacing and other alignment issues. This happens whenever moving across platforms, even when using Word on both platforms. For simple documents, sometimes an .rtf file will behave better but lose format functions specific to Word.

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded Libre Office 3.5 to 4.2 and then i installed `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` through Ubuntu Software Center.

Now I am able to choose MS Font styles, so it gives similar alignment.

I'm not sure about this one, but my issue has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

LibreOffice will attempt to display a file from Microsoft Office the best it can but unfortunately there will be issues sometimes.

The best thing you can do is save the document in Microsoft Office as a .odt (Open Document Text) file as this is the same format LibreOffice uses and so it may show up better.